# How can I make the navigation drawer to not close the left drawer completely?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I have an Activity that its root element is a DrawerLayout, the DrawerLayout has a ListView child that acts as the left view of the drawer layout.

The question is:

How can I force the left drawer's list view to not close completely ?

I want its closed state to be like the photo below

[image]

I am currently using Android's guide to [Create a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

I am open for any other library - [like Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) - if that accomplishes my goal.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I know this Question is 1 year old, but if anyone has the same requirement as the OP, then use [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) instead of `NavigationDrawer`

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SlidingPaneLayout, it's similar to NavigationDrawer.
Check [this](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html) tutorial to find out how to reach it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use that far leftmost menu as a fragment within your activity.  Upon opening the NAv Drawer, you can still have it show the menus that are 2nd or 3rd level.  This is pretty standard for our app, with a menu exposed and further menus available upon opening the drawer

Comment: But if I made a left most menu as a fragment won't a part of it will be visible when the drawer is opened ? I can hide that fragment but I'm not sure how the UX will be with hiding and showing the left most menu.